# (html) Tel:phone-number not working

Tags: html

have done a complete search and cannot get this click-to-call html to work.
Have tried;

```
<a href="tel:000000000">000000000</a>
<a href="tel://000000000">000000000</a>
<a href="callto:000000000">000000000</a>
<a href="callto://000000000">000000000</a>
```

This is the webpage i'm trying to get it to work on http://www.glasgowbuildinginspections.com.au/phone/

I can load the page locally file:///D:/Downloads/index.html and it works, but the page says it can't load server side files which might be what is stopping it.
Any thoughts?

Comment: put country code like this <a href="tel:+13174562564">317-456-2564</a>

Comment: country code doesn't work either. even if i change the link to mailto: it doesnt work as an email link, very strange

Comment: are you generating HTML? then please make sure it generates correct HTML for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<a href="tel:+000000000">000000000</a>
```

Comment: No, that didnt work either. Its like there might be a higher script running, I didnt create the page's, it was done in muse by another developer.